# running Android app from ADT fails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, tablet

I am following this simple tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

When I view the graphical editor/wysiwug I see the correct thing. A screen with one input text and a button.
But, when I run the app, I get a blank screen with the default Android buttons to the right.
In the logs, I see:
(normal)

```
[2013-11-18 16:07:37 - hello] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-18 16:07:37 - hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-11-18 16:07:37 - hello] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google'
[2013-11-18 16:07:37 - hello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google'
```

(error)

```
[2013-11-18 16:07:43 - Emulator] libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau   
[2013-11-18 16:07:43 - Emulator] libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
```

Not sure if connected or not. What am I missing here? I installed ADT and then started following the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

haha...All you have to do is, relax, sit back, wait 10 minutes.
The virtual machine (Android emulator) takes loooong time to fully initialize.